# Using Talend with Oracle eBS and Sybase

Tags: oracle, sybase, sap-ase, talend

I would like to use Talend to extract data from Sybase ASE 15.0.3 and import the data back to Oracle eBS.
I need to know how I will be able to run the job from eBS and do I need to install any Talend software on eBS database Server or the Sybase Server?

Answer (score 0):

Talend job is a java program, it can be ran in any system that have Java installed, after exporting your project, you dont need to install Talend. Please see here: [Exporting a Job script and executing it outside of Talend Studio](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Exporting+a+Job+script+and+executing+it+outside+of+Talend+Studio)